# Is it possible to have two residence permits (one of UK and one of France)?

Tags: united-kingdom, schengen, residence-cards

I am working in UK and my spouse is working in France. Can I apply for a working permit of UK and spouse permit in France, so I can move between two countries easier?

Thank you very much,